# Is this a threading issue?

Tags: jquery, python, multithreading, each, cherrypy

I'm using CherryPy 5.0.1 as my server-side framework.

The following code performs searches on the local disk's files. It searches for certain strings fed by the front-end's AJAX calls.

```
import cherrypy
import os
import os.path
import json


def searchForFiles(search_path, base_filename):
    directory = os.path.abspath(search_path)
    files = []
    for f in os.listdir(directory):
        if os.path.isfile(f):
            files.append(f)
    hit = []
    for f in files:
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(f, '*' + base_filename + '*'):
            hit.append(f)
    hit = json.dumps(hit)
    return hit



class GUI_DB_Interface:

    # whatever codes here......

    @cherrypy.expose
    def searchForFiles(self, search_path, base_filename):
        return searchForFiles(search_path, base_filename)
```

The front-end code:

```
  var searchSimilarFiles = function(event, filename_base) {
    var $uls = $('div#overview_box ul.existing_files');
    var current_input = $('input#primary_input').val();
    $.each($uls, function(index, ul) {
      var path_name = $(ul).siblings('div.folder_info')
        .find('div.path_name').data("path");
      $.post('searchForFiles', {
        'search_path': path_name,
        'base_filename': current_input
      }, function(databack) {
        var lis = JSON.parse(databack);
        $(ul).empty();
        console.log(lis);
        for (l in lis) {
          $(ul).append("<li>" + lis[l] + "</li>");
        }
      });
    });
  };
```

My code has the following problems:

1. There are four different divs containing four different `search_path` information using `$.each()` function to make an AJAX call to the backend service. On a click event there supposed to be four different calls, but now only the first div really works.
2. Actually the calls are successfully made for all four divs by $.each(), and the service on the back-end can be found successfully, returning status code 200, but only the first div actually gets the right result, **the other three always get an empty array**.
3. logging on the back-end shows that the problem is in the back end. the 'files' variable for the first call returns the right array, while other three return empty arrays.

Comment: Is your search file supposed to only search the specified directory - _if so consider using_ `glob.glob` - or to also search subdirectories _in which case `os.walk` would be your friend_?

Comment: @SteveBarnes - OP would still have to check `isdir`. `fnmatch` is basically what glob is doing so I don't see any real difference.

Comment: it would be useful to log directory and filename to see if they are sane.